# chrome positions elements different from firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, position

I have these buttons on top of my page and the issue is that chrome displays these buttons with 80px more to the right. What am I doing wrong?

this is the style of one button:

```
#engleza1{
position: relative;
top:0px;
left: 788px;
width: 51px;
height:42px;
}
#engleza1:hover{
position: relative;
top:0px;
left: 788px;
width: 51px;
height:42px;
background:url(../images/engleza.png) no-repeat;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

and this is the style of their wrapper:

```
#wrap{
width:100%;
height: 1950px;
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
background:url(../ong.png) center no-repeat;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="engleza1">
//nothing here
</div>
...
</div>
```

Comment: Hi now it's fine http://jsfiddle.net/gPGTf/1/

Comment: yes, I see that on jsfiddle it is ok. so something is wrong with my ther code that is making these divs behave like this, no?

Comment: ok, I think I know what the issue might be. Chrome is displaying the background image: ong.png bigger. So the wrap div must be bigger in chrome, this is why those divs are misplaced. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your some code is repeat so rmove it and replce this

```
#wrap{
height: 1950px;
text-align: center;
margin:0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
background:red;
}
#engleza1{
position: relative;
top:0px;
  left:788px;
width: 51px;
height:42px;
  background:yellow;
}
#engleza1:hover{
background:green;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

for the demo change to according to your layout

***[live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gPGTf/1/)***

Comment: yea, but I think the best way is to use some sprites and solve it like that. thanks!